# Is the occurence of $4653$ in both expressions a coincidence?

Tags: number-theory, pseudoprimes

The smallest composite strong-probable prime to base $2$ greater than $10^5$ is $$10^5+4653$$ and the smallest composite strong-probable prime to base $2$ greater than $10^6$ is $$10^6+4653$$

> Is it a coincidence that we have the number $4653$ in both expressions or is there an explanation ?

Comment: Since there is very little objectively special about powers of $10$, apart from them being powers of natural numbers, I'd lean against coincidence. But I don't know. Do you observe the same pattern for powers of other numbers? Like what is the smallest composite strong-probable prime to base $2$ larger than $12^7$ and $12^8$, respectively? What about other bases?

Comment: @Arthur So far, I did not find further patterns.

Comment: @Arthur: I agree re the comment about powers of $10$. Kindly see my answer below using powers other than $10$.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of strong pseudoprimes to base $2$ is given by [A001262](https://oeis.org/A001262),

$$2047, 3277, 4033, 4681, 8321, 15841, 29341, 42799, 49141, 52633, 65281\dots$$

What we are looking for are two entries of form,

> $$a^m+b\\a^n+b$$

Using just the first $10000$ entries, we are bound to find such pairs. Hence, we have your,

$$10^5+4653,\quad 10^6+4653$$

as well as,

$$10^3 + \color{blue}{163}\times6027,\quad  10^5 + \color{blue}{163}\times6027$$

$$9^2 + 3952,\quad  9^3 + 3952$$

$$8^5 + 45067409,\quad  8^9 + 45067409$$

$$7^4 + 1323442, \quad  7^6 + 1323442$$

and so on. (Note the surprising cameo played by my favorite number $163$.)

In conclusion, these pairs are probably just coincidences, though the first one is noticeable because of our base-$10$ notation.